# Exclude empty fields from jaxb marshalling

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a POJO which i want to marshall and send as xml, but also to unmarshall the data which is returned from the same webservice. However, there are certain fields in this POJO, which i do not want to send, but which may be in the returned xml from the server.

The problem here is, that if i for instance have an int field called status, and i dont actually set any value for this field (since i dont want to send this field to the server), JAXB still creates a 0 element in the xml.

So my question is: How can i prevent this behaviour, and simply ommit the field, but still be able to read the value of the element that is returned from the server?

Kind regards.

Comment: Use an `Integer` rather than an `int`, and then JAXB will omit the null value.

Answer (score 7):

To repeat my comment as an answer...

Since `int` cannot represent "no value", you could instead use an `Integer`.  If this is `null`, then JAXB will omit the field when marshalling.

Answer (score -1):

With JAXB Integer will be converted to 0 (not null).